# Xcode: 67,000 build errors. How do I fix this?

Tags: iphone, xcode, character-encoding

Did I just break some kind of record?

[image]

Ok so this is actually a serious question :)

What I did was drag one of my code files onto my desktop. I then deleted the file from Xcode, thinking I had a better way to code something. Turns out I didn't, and I want to reuse my old file.

But... I emptied the trash can in between. I didn't think this would be a problem, I just dragged the desktop version of the file back into Xcode. But now, the file is all messed up - it looks like what you get if you open a .jpeg or anything else with a text editor. I build it with this and get 67,000 errors :o

Somehow the character encoding or something has changed - anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: ok here's another photo. No, its not photoshop.

[image]

Comment: Aren't using version control, or at least, Time Machine?

Comment: What's version control? I didn't plug in my time machine hard drive between creating and deleting the file :(

Comment: looks like this is a photoshop job

Comment: This might be the result of just one error in a header file. However nobody will be able to help you if you show the error count. What about showing at least the first error message?

Comment: The errors are not the real problem, it is caused by the fact that the whole file looks something like this: "?í<JLJ™S)¥S)àò®∏¿TqJA±ë=$165FDF32-C41C-3063-984".

Comment: Not photoshop, will upload another screenshot in a sec

Comment: Your file is junked. It won't compile because it doesn't contain source code anymore. :)

Comment: Yea, the annoying thing is that I didn't change anything between moving it to the desktop and back. It couldn't just be that the character encoding has somehow changed?

Comment: All similar to screenshot above - I have 2408 errors of 'stray \302 in program'.

Comment: Did you try setting the encoding using the Get Info dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file you thought you dragged to the desktop is not a -- or no longer a --  source file, plain and simple.

You either dragged some other file to the desktop or your computer's filesystem is going bad and it trashed the file.  Given that your system still boots, I'd assume the former before the latter.

Unless you accidentally compressed the file or something, you will need to recover the file from your backup or from revision control.  If you don't have those, then you'll probably have to start over on that source.

Comment: Ok you're right - what I did was try dragging another file from Xcode to the desktop. It turns out it doesn't copy the file, rather, the desktop file is just a reference to the actual file. Wish I knew this earlier.

Comment: Lesson learnt: use time machine + version control. Guess I learnt the hard way :s

Comment: Actually, your lesson should be to use version control and some variety of off-site backup. Github, Beanstalk, etc. are all exceedingly good and cheap.